# Append Multiple Objects into Existing Array Using JSON_MODIFY

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

The problem was in appending new JSON array to the existing JSON array:

Suppose I have the following JSON Array
`[{"id": 1, "data": "One"}, {"id": 2, "data": "Two"}]`

How do I append `[{"id": 3, "data": "Three"}, {"id": 4, "data": "Four"}]` to it using `JSON_MODIFY`?

resulting value for updated column:
`[{"id": 1, "data": "One"}, {"id": 2, "data": "Two"}, {"id": 3, "data": "Three"}, {"id": 4, "data": "Four"}]`

Answer (score 5):

I don't think, that you can merge two JSON arrays with one `JSON_MODIFY()` call, but the following statement (using `JSON_MODIFY()`) is a possible solution:

Statement:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(500)='[{"id": 1, "data": "One"}, {"id": 2, "data": "Two"}]'
DECLARE @new NVARCHAR(500)='[{"id": 3, "data": "Three"}, {"id": 4, "data": "Four"}]'

SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(
   @json,
   'append $',
   JSON_QUERY([value])
)
FROM OPENJSON(@new)

SELECT @json
```

Result:

```
[{"id": 1, "data": "One"}, {"id": 2, "data": "Two"},{"id": 3, "data": "Three"},{"id": 4, "data": "Four"}]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for JSON arrays of numbers for some reason e.g. `DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(500)='[1, 2]'` and `DECLARE @new NVARCHAR(500)='[3, 4]'`. The error is `JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 1.`

Comment: @Tagc, the reason for this error is the fact, that you have two JSON arrays of scalar values, not JSON arrays of JSON objects. In this case you need to replace `JSON_QUERY([value])` with `CONVERT(int, [value])`. Note, that the actual statement depends on the structure of parsed JSON arrays. Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov thanks for sharing this. Possible to format this as an update statement to an existing row in a table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "JSON_MODIFY" function and append key to modify JSON object like below:

> [SQL-FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=51740a193d14a05068dda3f08e0c1afe)
>
> It's for individual JSON array:

```
DECLARE @json1 NVARCHAR(500)='[{"id": 1, "data": "One"}, {"id": 2, "data": "Two"}]';
DECLARE @json2 NVARCHAR(500)='[{"id": 3, "data": "Three"}, {"id": 4, "data": "Four"}]';


SELECT t.id, t.[data]
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json1) WITH(id int,[data] NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json2) WITH(id int,[data] NVARCHAR(MAX))
) t
FOR JSON PATH;
```

> It's for individual JSON hash:

```
DECLARE @info NVARCHAR(500)='[{"id": 1, "data": "One"}, {"id": 2, "data": "Two"}]';

PRINT @info;

SET @info = JSON_MODIFY(@info, 'append $', JSON_QUERY('{"id": 3, "data": "Three"}'))
SET @info = JSON_MODIFY(@info, 'append $', JSON_QUERY('{"id": 4, "data": "Four"}'))

PRINT @info;
```

Comment: I want to append the whole array at a time, not an individual object

Comment: Please, check the updated answer, may it helps you.

Comment: NO, I want using JSON_MODIFY

Comment: How can we specify the index? Need a add a new json string to a specific index?

Comment: Please, looking inside of fiddle where I mention in last section, try with " order by id asc/desc" https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=601d199d2cd9cf287ec3c8a5c472044d

Comment: @jainvikram444  thanks for sharing this. Possible to format this as an update statement to an existing row in a table?

Answer (score 1):

## Workaround I found for my project

I have two tables t1 and t2 which are identical in structure. Table t1 keeps records of supplier certificates. Table t2 gets with API new certificates obtained by supplier. So Table t1 shall be updated with new certificates from Table t2. Certificates data are placed in JSON array of objects, similar to the example of the topic starter.

## Task

JSON array in t1 col JSON_t1 shall be appended with JSON array from t2 col JSON_t2. Here's the structure simplified for the example purposes:

#### Table "t1"

| recordId | JSON_t1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"id": 1, "data": "One"}, {"id": 2, "data": "Two"}] |

#### Table "t2"

| recordId | JSON_t2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"id": 3, "data": "Three"}, {"id": 4, "data": "Four"}] |

#### RESULT

| appended t1.JSON_t1 |
| --- |
| [{"id": 1, "data": "One"}, {"id": 2, "data": "Two"},{"id": 3, "data": "Three"}, {"id": 4, "data": "Four"}] |

## SQL method

```
SELECT
t1.JSON_t1,
t2.JSON_t2,
concat('[', replace(replace(json_modify(t1.JSON_t1, 'append $', json_query(t2.JSON_t2)), '[', ''), ']', ''), ']') as "appended t1.JSON_t1"
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.recordId = t2.recordId
```

## Method explained

1. JSON_t2 is converted to JSON format with `json_query(t2.JSON_t2)` to avoid escaping of characters
2. JSON_t1 is appended with JSON_t2 with `json_modify(t1.JSON_t1, 'append $', json_query(t2.JSON_t2))` resulting to the following output: *[{"id": 1, "data": "One"}, {"id": 2, "data": "Two"},**[**{"id": 3, "data": "Three"}, {"id": 4, "data": "Four"}**]**]*. Note square brackets in **bold** which shall be fixed as this will not be a correct final array of objects.
3. Final JSON is stripped from all square brackets with `replace` method used two times: for "[" and "]" `replace(replace(json_modify(t1.JSON_t1, 'append $', json_query(t2.JSON_t2)), '[', ''), ']', '')`
4. Final JSON is added with two square brackets at start and end to make a valid JSON array `concat('[', replace(replace(json_modify(t1.JSON_t1, 'append $', json_query(t2.JSON_t2)), '[', ''), ']', ''), ']')`
5. You can test if the final JSON is valid with [ISJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

### Points to note

- If you don't use `json_query`, you get the following result:
  `[{"id": 1, "data": "One"}, {"id": 2, "data": "Two"},"[{\"id\": 3, \"data\": \"Three\"}, {\"id\": 4, \"data\": \"Four\"}]"]`. See more on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/solve-common-issues-with-json-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#prevent-double-escaped-json-in-for-json-output).
- I tried to strip from square brackets only JSON_t2 and use `json_modify` like this `json_modify(t1.JSON_t1, 'append $', json_query('{"id": 3, "data": "Three"}, {"id": 4, "data": "Four"}')` but this results to appending only the first item from the JSON_t2 like this: *[{"id": 1, "data": "One"}, {"id": 2, "data": "Two"},{"id": 3, "data": "Three"}]*
- NB. if you have nested arrays, this method is not suitable. In my case it works well since I have a simple array of objects (certificates with various key/value pairs like validity, type, issue date, etc.)